# Use scroll bars on child controls in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an explorer type window that I am trying to display in WPF.

```
<Grid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <telerik:RadTreeView Grid.Column="0" Name="ExplorerTree"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <telerik:RadListBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
</Grid>
```

However, when I expand an object within the tree view, the scroll bar appears on the grid causing the entire window to scroll rather than just the contents of the tree view. What do I need to change to make the contents of the tree view scroll instead?  I don't want to set it to a specific height as I would like the height of the tree view to adjust with the height of the parent in which it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just stop trying to set ScrollViewer properties altogether you should get the desired result as both RadTreeView and RadListBox will display a ScrollViewer automatically as needed (unless you have something else in the rest of your XAML that interferes with their normal behavior). I used both these controls extensively without setting any ScrollViewer properties in XAML and that's what they do automatically although you might have to set their VerticalAlignment to stretch... not sure about that.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <telerik:RadTreeView Grid.Column="0" Name="ExplorerTree"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  <telerik:RadListBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working for me.  The parent still gets the scrollbar rather than the treeview or the listview.